# Using PIP to install jupyterlab

Tags: python, macos, pip, dyld

So I recently decided that I wanted to do Python again but this time I wanted it for AI, so I ended up wanting to use Jupyter Notebook. However, when I use the command `pip install jupyterlab`, it gives me the following error.

`dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python Reason: image not found zsh: abort      pip install notebook`

So I decided to check my `echo $PATH` and I got this

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

So what I understood from this is that my system is using python 3.9? <- I'm not sure about this to be completely honest. Going back to the `pip install jupyterlab` it gives another error in which is gives me this

```
Process:               Python [5911]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.6 (3.7.6)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [5755]
Responsible:           Terminal [4007]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-09-15 09:34:31.540 -0400
OS Version:            macOS 11.4 (20F71)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.4 (18P4663)
Anonymous UUID:        97B6C1B1-F670-238C-FB42-76BAB028DC08

Sleep/Wake UUID:       9DA5F457-58C0-4989-8702-A75276E1B82F

Time Awake Since Boot: 30000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  dyld: No shared cache present
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (3.7.6 - 3.7.6) <266DE8C4-14E3-83DB-D4C7-E809D96C1A79> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
    0x7fff61bc9000 -     0x7fff61c64fff  dyld (852) <1AC76561-4F9A-34B1-BA7C-4516CACEAED7> /usr/lib/dyld
```

All in all how do I use pip to install Jupyterlab? I am very new to all this so I didn't know what the right information was to give so I gave everything I saw.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have Developer tools installed? `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Note: Google colab, for example, provides online, free jupyter environment so you don't need to install things locally

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3` rather than `pip`? It is recommended for Python 3+.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that. But would you recommend I do install?

Comment: @Tang Macos system Python2 doesn't have pip, so that wouldn't matter

Comment: Personally, I would suggest uninstalling all Python's that look like they came from official Python site (at least every version below 3.8). You can also [try using pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) install other versions and use the pip that they come with. Overall, DYLD errors are not specific to Python/pip, and you should be able to search for errors around that

Comment: @Leafy with command `pip3 install jupyterlab`.
@OncCriketeer, are you sure of that? I sometimes had positive impact of using `pip3` over `pip` when I had multiple versions of Python on my MacOS (under which Python 2.7).

Comment: `pip3` actually worked thank you @TanguyH

Comment: @Tang If you'd installed Python2 from brew or anaconda, it might  have had pip, but if the PATH has Python3 folder first, pip will resolve to that... However, `python3 -m pip` is more proper usage

Comment: @Leafy, can you flag my answer as correct in that case ?

Comment: But why does my `$PATH` have python 3.9. if it is using python 3.7.6?

Comment: @OneCricketeer "python3.10 -m pip install jupyterlab" works for me. Thanks a lot for the suggestion of "python3 -m pip".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either you do it through anaconda: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/index.html

Or, it seems you are using Python 3.7. It is recommended to use pip3 in that case. Have you tried `pip3 install jupyterlab`?